# Do all Facebook Graph API calls require HTTPS starting October 1st?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, https

I have an app I host myself which makes use of the graph API. I have already update to OAuth 2.0 but **do all of my API calls now require that I use HTTPS?**  Will Facebook auto redirect calls that are made without HTTPS?

I've noticed that all of the API documentation shows https URLs which makes me worried.

Comment: You would need to ask facebook.

Comment: Well if they're auto-redirecting http calls to https then I think that answers your question with a yes.

Comment: They aren't auto-redirecting currently. My question is, what's going to happen on October 1st when you type this into a browser:
    
http://graph.facebook.com/{username}

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this change will affect your Graph API calls, as they are already using HTTPS.

```
Example:  https://graph.facebook.com/user/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
```

The Oct 1st HTTPS thing refers to your canvas URL - it has to be HTTPS.

```
Example:  https://www.myfacebookapp.com
```

Comment: My graph API calls aren't already using HTTPS. That is my concern. Go type a graph call into a browser with HTTP. It works today. Will it work on October 1st?

Answer (score 2):

The October 1st deadline does not dictate that grahp calls must be sent over HTTPS.  Any call that uses an access_token is already required to use SSL, and more and more calls that were open (didn't require an access_token) are starting to require an access_token so it is recommended that you start switching all your graph calls to https as you are able.  Facebook won't forward non-http requests over to https.